# Clustering algorithms with R

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I'm actually trying to create a heat map. So I need to find a suitable clustering method.

Here is an exemple of my data frame :

df1

```
  g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9 g10 g11
1  1  1  0  0  3  4  4  0  0   6   0
2  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0   0   8
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2   0   0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2   0   0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0

structure(list(g1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), g3 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g4 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), g5 = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g6 = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g7 = c(4L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g8 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L), g9 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L), g10 = c(6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g11 = c(0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

The heat map is such that I do not want to move the rows, here are the settings I used with Heatmap function:

```
ht1 = Heatmap(df1, cluster_rows=as.dendrogram(a), 
              column_title = "Heatmap",
              top_annotation = ha_column2,col=c("white","blue","red","green","yellow"),
              column_names_side = NULL,
              show_heatmap_legend = FALSE,show_column_names = F,
              clustering_distance_columns ="euclidean",
              clustering_method_rows = "war.D2",
              row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6))
```

and here is the result :

[image: picture1]

the corresponding matrix with the clustering done is:

```
g11 g1  g2  g3  g4  g8  g9  g5  g10 g6  g7
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   3   6   4   4
8   0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

But the issue is here, I'm looking for a clustering method that takes into account the disposition of the number into columns.
For instance if I have :

```
A B C D E
0 2 9 0 4
1 0 0 8 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

I would like to gather A and D together because they have both a disposition:

```
0
number
0
0
```

and gather B , E and C together because they have a disposition:

```
number 
0
0
0
```

and get :

```
A   D   B   E   C
0   0   2   4   9
1   8   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
```

if I apply this rule to the first array i should get this:

```
  g1 g2 g5 g6 g7 g10 g3 g4 g11 g8 g9
1  1  1  3  4  4   6  0  0   0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0   0  2  2   8  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0   0  2  2
4  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0   0  2  2
5  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0   0  0  0
```

Does anyone have a good idea of a clustering algorithm to do it with R ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you only want the clustering to see if numbers are zero or not, you could transform the matrix to replace all non-zeroes with 1, and then apply your clustering method of choice.

Comment: @JonSpring But I need the other number informations as well in my heatmap, that is the point..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr` from the `tidyverse` meta-package. I suspect there's a simpler way to do this in base R...

First I determine column order using "disposition" only, by making a version of `df1` that concatenates all the rows in each column and treats all non-zeros as 1s. By sorting that, we have the order we want. Then I grab `df1` with columns in that order.

```
library(tidyverse)
col_order <- data_frame(cols = names(df1),
                  concat = apply(df1, 2, paste0, collapse = "")) %>%
  mutate(concat_binary = concat %>% str_replace_all("[123456789]", "1")) %>%
  arrange(desc(concat_binary)) %>%
  pull(cols)

df1 %>% 
  select(col_order)

#  g1 g2 g5 g6 g7 g10 g3 g4 g11 g8 g9
#1  1  1  3  4  4   6  0  0   0  0  0
#2  0  0  0  0  0   0  2  2   8  0  0
#3  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0   0  2  2
#4  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0   0  2  2
#5  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0   0  0  0
```